# calling child url from parent page

Tags: javascript

I will need to call child url from parent url. Both are having **different host** .
test.html is stored in the server, [www.web1.com](http://www.web1.com) will load test.html and display this on [www.prod.com](http://www.prod.com)

I am trying to capture the url that is showing from website1[www.web1.com] on website2[www.prod.com]

Flow is as shown below

[image]

- server and website1 are linked and are using the same host hence there will be no issue

inside test.html , i have used `console.log(window.top.location.href)` , this will display "www.web1.com" on my console.log

on [www.prod.com](http://www.prod.com) , it will load [www.web1.com](http://www.web1.com) which consist of test.html , when window.top.location.href script that was declared in test.html and place in web 1 is loaded in website 2, this will cause `DOMException cross origin error` because the script is reading [www.prod.com](http://www.prod.com) instead of [www.web1.com](http://www.web1.com).  I have read through some source to use `document.referrer` , i am wondering if this is possible for web 2 to display "www.web1.com" on console.log when it loads web 1 on web 2

ideally , if we use window.location, this will load the top url of web ,

1. if this is used on web1 , it will print [www.web1.com](http://www.web1.com)
2. if this is used on web2 , it will print [www.prod.com](http://www.prod.com)

But as for the usecase i stated above, web2 should load and display web1 url on web2 console.log